# Unable to pass class instance to constructor

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have installed this package https://github.com/Intervention/image with composer.  I have added

`'IntImage' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'`

to config/app under aliases

I get the following error and cant figure out what I am doing incorrectly I am sure it has something to do with namespacing /autoloading but app/acme is in the psr-o section of composer.json

> 'Argument 1 passed to
>   Acme\Services\Images\InterventionImageEditor::__construct() must be an
>   instance of IntImage, none given, called in
>   /var/www/app/ACme/Providers/ImageEditorServiceProvider.php on line 14
>   and defined' in
>   /var/www/app/Acme/Services/Images/InterventionImageEditor.php:11

I have the following directory structure

```
app
  acme
    Providers
      ImageEditorServiceProvider.php
    Services
      Images
        ImageEditorInterface.php
        InterventionImageEditor.php
```

and the content of the files

*ImageEditorServiceProvider.php*

```
<?php namespace Acme\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Acme\Services\Images\InterventionImageEditor;

/**
*
*/
class ImageEditorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Acme\Services\Images\ImageEditorInterface', function () {
            return new InterventionImageEditor();
        });
    }
}
```

*ImageEditorInterface.php*

```
<?php namespace Acme\Services\Images;

interface ImageEditorInterface
{
    public function hello();
}
```

*InterventionImageEditor.php*

```
<?php namespace Acme\Services\Images;

use IntImage;

/**
*
*/
class InterventionImageEditor implements ImageEditorInterface
{
    protected $imageeditor;

    public function __construct(IntImage $imageeditor)
    {
        $this->imageeditor = $imageeditor;
    }

    public function hello()
    {
        $hello = 'hello';

        return $hello;
    }
}
```

Can I

```
Use IntImage;
```

in this way because it is a facade or am I missing something?

edit to include solution;

changing the service provider to the following resolved the problem

```
<?php namespace Acme\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Acme\Services\Images\InterventionImageEditor;
use IntImage;

/**
*
*/
class ImageEditorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Acme\Services\Images\ImageEditorInterface', function () {
            $intimage = new IntImage;
            return new InterventionImageEditor($intimage);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from `ImageEditorServiceProder.php`:

```
$this->app->bind('Acme\Services\Images\ImageEditorInterface', function () {
  return new InterventionImageEditor();
});
```

Here you are instantiating the `InterventionImageEditor` without any parameters.  You `InterventionImageEditor` requires one parameter of type `IntImage`.

If there are places where you won't have `IntImage` when instantiating `InterventionImageEditor` then you need to update your `InterventionImageEditor::__construct` so that it accepts `null`(possibly).

```
function __construct(IntImage $imageeditor = null)
{
    if (is_null($imageeditor)) {
        // Construct a default imageeditor
        // $imageeditor = new ...;
    }

    $this->imageeditor = $imageeditor;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. IntImage is an instance of the intervention/image class sp InterventionImageEditor will always need it.  However why wont InterventionImageEditor get IntImage itself from the 'Use IntImage;' code at the top of the file?

Comment: Seems like I have to pass IntImage from the Service Provider and then reference it in InterventionImageEditor as well.  I thought I only had to do it in the latter.  If you have the time to explain to me why this is as an edit in your answer I would appreciate.  If not thanks for heling anyway

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure you can using IntImage because this file is Facades.

if you want to extending the intervention class. you should add Intervention\Image\Image to your ImageEditorServiceProvider.

```
use Intervention\Image\Image;

class ImageEditorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Acme\Services\Images\ImageEditorInterface', function () {

            return new InterventionImageEditor(new Image);
        });
    }
}
```